# Bar chart using dataframe Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am working on pandas dataframe (data_agg_clust) having below sample data:

```
           KPIPred
Cluster 
9-11    125.872327
18-20   120.084786
15-17   112.328802
12-14   109.752560
21-23   106.128234
```

I would like to create a barchart using matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()

data_agg_clust.plot.bar(x="Cluster", y="KPIPred", rot=70, title="Predicted Volume of impressions");    
plot.show(block=True);
```

But unfortunately I got this error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2021.05/envs/jupiter/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2021.05/envs/jupiter/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2021.05/envs/jupiter/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Cluster'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception
```

It seems like it didn't recognize "Cluster" column.
How can I fix this error?

Comment: It seems like `Cluster` is your DataFrame index. Try calling `data_agg_clust.reset_index()` before plotting.

Comment: Please don't use semicolons in your python code if you can avoid it. The only reason they exist is so you can use the `-c` switch from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataframe's index has a name, pandas will distinguish it visually by printing it on a line below the column names. In this case `Cluster` is the name of your index.

The simplest solution is to leave `x` alone: it will default to the index if you don't supply a column name:

```
data_agg_clust.plot.bar(y="KPIPred", rot=70, title="Predicted Volume of impressions")
```

Another solution is to call [`data_agg_clust.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to convert the index into a column that can be used for plotting:

```
data_agg_clust.reset_index().plot.bar(x="Cluster", y="KPIPred", rot=70, title="Predicted Volume of impressions")
```